# How do I search for comments in Visual Studio? (VS 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

Is it possible to include comments in a search? Or maybe even exclude code and search for comments only?

Like for example

```
int a = 1;
//int b = 2;
```

If I search for `int` I will only find the `int` which is not commented. I want to find the commented one.

*edit*

another thing I just noticed. When I search for things in xaml I cannot find them either. example:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="veryImportant"/>
```

cannot be found by searching for for example  `TextBlock` or `Name` or `veryImportant`

Could it be possible to find it somehow?

Comment: Are you searching with the whole-word option? If you are searching with CTRL + F, it is the second icon in the second row.

Comment: @David yes that was it, Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio does allow for string searching in comments, although, in your example, it is possible that you have it set to "Match whole word" -- can you confirm that this is not the case?
[image: VS Find string]

Comment: Oh you were right. Sorry about that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CTRL + f` , you can do a simple text find which will include comments.